# Непонятное поведение переменной. Наверное связано со Scope. NodeJs, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Доброго времени суток!

Есть цепочка модулей, которая формирует строку запроса в БД, делает этот запрос и дает ответ. Проблему расписал в комментариях к коду. Мне кажется так будет понятнее.

```
function findInDb(data, callback){
    //функция формирует и возвращает строку запроса для БД
    formQuerystring(data, (query) =>{
        //посел получения строки запроса  открываю подключение к БД
            mongodb.connect((err, client)=>{
                var db = client.db("goods");
                //подключаюсь к коллекции
                db.collection(collectionName,(err, collection) =>{
                    сonsole.log(query) //{"$and":[{"visible":true},{"article":{"$in":[16]}}]}
                    //запускаю поиск документов соответствующих критерию поиска
                    collection.find(query).sort(sortValue).skip(skip).limit(limit).toArray((err, result)=>{
                        //теперь необходимо узнать кол-во документов соответствующих критерию поиска (для пагинации)

                        //проблема здесь!
                        console.log(query) // возвращает undefined 
                        collection.count(query,(err, count) =>{
                            var f ={};
                            f.result = result;
                            f.count = count;
                            client.close();
                            return callback(f);
                        })
                    })
                })
            })
    })
}
```

Почему `query` возвращает - `undefined`?

NodeJs версии - 8.9.4

MongoDB - 3.0

модуль MongoDD для NodeJS - 3.0

Comment: _сonsole.log(query) //{"$and":[{"visible":true},{"article":{"$in":[16]}}]}_ а вот тут всегда верно выводит?

Comment: `console.log(query)` - зачем так глубоко? Если `query` равно `undefined`, то это можно выяснить уже перед комментарием `//посел ...`.Есть какая-то связь между тем, что в `data`, и неопределенной `query`?

Comment: @Grundy, да, там всегда верно

Comment: @Igor, не совсем понял связь между расположением комментария и переменной. Комментарии для вопроса написаны. Связь `data` с `query` есть - в зависомости от того, что в `data` формируется и `query`. Но заход в функцию `formQuerystring` - происходит 1 раз. И `query` я нигде не меняю, только использую при обращении к БД. Меня сбивает то, что проблема возникает периодически.

Comment: Объект не может стать `undefined` просто так. если на уровне выше значение всегда корректно, а на уровне ниже - `undefined` значит либо предоставлен не весь код либо используется еще одна локальная переменная либо параметр с тем же именем

Comment: @Grundy, - только что понял, что `undefined` возвращает всегда((

Comment: @Igor, только что понял, что undefined возвращает всегда((

Comment: не исключена опечатка в имени переменной, например русская `e` вместо английской или наоборот

Comment: Есть какая-то связь между тем, что в `data`, и неопределенной `query`? Добавьте `console.log(data, query);` в начало функции `formQuerystring(data, (query) =>{ ...`. И анализируйте содержимое `data` для случаев неопределенной `query`.

Comment: @Grundy @Igor - спасибо Вам. Я неправильно определил проблему. Запутал сам себя и Вас. Проблема есть - возникает переодически, но она видимо где-то в функции  формирующей `query`.  Буду разбираться.